# Facebook Page Tab allowfullscreen attribute

Tags: iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently have problems with setting the allowfullscreen attribute to the iframe element of my Facebook Page Tab application as I wanted to be able to display my Page Tab application in full screen mode. Please help me.